# SharePoint 2013 search results with out security trim

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I got a requirement to display SharePoint search results without item level permissions. Once user selects then it should say access denied to the user. Any solution? I tried with security trimmer but no use.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about any out of the box way of achieving this.

Your best option is to extend Search Core Results Web Part and create a new one. Inside that run the code in Elevate Mode.

This will bring back results without Security. And when user tries to open if he/she don't have access, then they will get redirected to access denied page.

Comment: Thanks Amal for your Quick Reply,But i tried that option but still no use i used this link http://www.lestersconyers.com/extending-search-web-parts/ to try to extend but in sharepoint 2013 it is not working.